# Is a filter a good way to accomplish a dynamic class in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular.js

I want to apply a different badge color with bootstrap depending on a number.

I wrote a filter to accomplish this...

```
angular.module('Demo')
    .filter('reserveStatus', function() {
        return function(num) {
            var klass = "";

            num = parseInt(num, 10);

            if (num > 2 && num < 5) {
                klass = "alert-success";
            }                    
            else if (num >= 5 && num < 10) {
                klass = "alert-warning";
            }
            else if (num >= 10) {
                klass = "alert-danger";
            }

            return klass;
        }
    });
```

And it's used with interpolation like this...

```
<span class="badget {{reserve.qty | reserveStatus}}"></span>
```

Is this a good way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fun question, I think this is okay.

I would name `klass` -> `class` and I would consider building a map for the values:

```
var classMap = [
  { from : 3 , to : 5       , class : 'alert-success' },
  { from : 5 , to : 10      , class : 'alert-warning' },
  { from : 10, to : Infinity, class : 'alert-danger'  }
];
```

Comment: I believe it is best practice to avoid using `class` as it is a reserved keyword for ECMAScript 6 (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar).

Comment: Extremely good point! +1 comment. It is though okay to use `class` as a property of an object according to JsHint, not so much as a variable name.